# Conversion to Dalvik format failed: Unable to execute dex: There is not enough space on the disk

Tags: android, eclipse

I tried updating my eclipse.ini file's contents at the end to -Xms512m -Xmx1024m, 
I also tried updating the project.properties with dex.force.jumbo= true.
Also tried restarting eclipse, clean the project.
Problem is still there, what can be the solution to this problem. I have gone through the answers available, what can be the solution to this problem.

Comment: Yes, it's your computer's memory issue. If you have outlook or any other software opened, then just closed them and try to open eclipse. Or restart your machine.

Comment: What answers were available, and at some point did you verify that you aren't actually out of disk space?

Comment: Found the solution, disk drive was full where I have kept the eclipse projects, by deleting some of other files, it is now working. Thanks guys for your answers.